# Cannot play YouTube videos in Firefox - Opera works?

Tags: firefox, video, flash, youtube

Since a couple of days it is not possible for me to watch YouTube videos in Firefox - nevertheless I installed Opera and tried it successfully to play videos with it.

What I tried so far (and did not work / change anything):

- started Firefox in safe mode
- reinstalled flash package `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`
- switched to HTML5 mode on youtube
- I also tried `cd; rm -r .adobe .macromedia`
- I enabled / disabled hardware acceleration

Always same result: Either error message

> an error occured

or only black screen with spinning wheel.

Can anybody please help?

Output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; dpkg -l | egrep 'flash|gnash|swf|lightspark'`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
Linux architect 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ii  flashplugin-installer                       11.2.202.346ubuntu0.13.10.1                   amd64        Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
```

And also tried with adobe package:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
Linux architect 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ii  adobe-flash-properties-gtk                  11.2.202.346-0saucy1                          amd64        GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
ii  adobe-flashplugin                           11.2.202.346-0saucy1                          amd64        Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
```

Comment: Have the exact same problem. I can watch YouTube in Chrome or Minitube, but suddenly no longer in Firefox. It happened out of nothing between watching 2 videos and nothing fixes it. 5 days now already.

Comment: Do you have HTTPS everywhere Firefox extension installed? I disabled it and now it works - the problem was with HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also affected (Ubuntu 12.04). To me it looks like the combination of Firefox and invoking YouTube videos using https fails. If you have HTTPS Everywhere installed, deactivate it for YouTube. But beware: Manual https requests on YouTube videos will still fail, plain http will work.

Cheers.